# Querying the Google ads API

Tags: java, object-oriented, unit-testing, api, ddd

I have a method which relies heavily on object supplied by third party APIs. Below is my working code, is there any scope of improvement?

```
public LineItem getLineItem(
      String networkId, String lineItemId) throws ApiException_Exception {
    LineItem lineItem = null;
    session.setCode(networkId); 
    LineItemServiceInterface lineItemService = servicesInterface.lineItemService(dfpSession);
    StatementBuilder statementBuilder =
        new StatementBuilder()
            .where("id = " + lineItemId.trim())
            .orderBy("id ASC")
            .limit(StatementBuilder.SUGGESTED_PAGE_LIMIT);
    LineItemPage lineItemPage =
        lineItemService.getLineItemsByStatement(statementBuilder.toStatement());
    if (lineItemPage != null && lineItemPage.getResults() != null) {
      lineItem = lineItemPage.getResults().get(0);
    }
    return lineItem;
  }
```

Every type used above belongs to third party code. I also need to know the good strategy to handle exceptions?

**Update 1**

One frequent issue I encounter and I am sure many if us will is that there is usually references to the third party type `LineItem` is sprinkled everywhere in the code base. Is this a good practice to leave it like that or should I wrap that type into my own type and use that instead?

Reference code [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/dfp_axis/src/main/java/dfp/axis/v201511/lineitemservice/GetAllLineItems.java).

Comment: Is your usage of `StatementBuilder` the recommended approach by the developers of that class? It looks ripe for [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)...

Comment: @h.j.k. seems yes, [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/dfp_axis/src/main/java/dfp/axis/v201511/lineitemservice/GetAllLineItems.java) is the reference.

Comment: But it looks like [bindings](http://googleads.github.io/googleads-java-lib/2.10.0/com/google/api/ads/dfp/axis/utils/v201602/StatementBuilder.html) are supported too, so you may want to try that out...

Comment: You mean to use replace string concatenation with the bindings, right?

Comment: Yes, see answer below.

Comment: I think the api is buggy, the binding is not working. I am getting `WHERE id = :lineItem ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 500`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### SQL statement construction

Your third-party library do support [bindings](http://googleads.github.io/googleads-java-lib/2.10.0/com/google/api/ads/dfp/axis/utils/v201602/StatementBuilder.html), so instead of `.where("id = " + lineItemId.trim())`, you should consider:

```
//  .where("id = " + lineItemId.trim())
    .where("id = :lineItem")
    .withBindVariableValue("lineItem", lineItemId.trim());
```

#### Early variable assignment

```
LineItem lineItem = null;
// ...
if (/* ... */) {
    lineItem = /* ... */;
}
return lineItem;
```

You usually should not need to declare the return result right at the start, perform the optional assignment, and then return from the method. You should just return below, without needing the `lineItem` variable:

```
// ...
if (/* ... */ ) {
    return /* ... */;
}
return null;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the pros of this?

Comment: In the unlikely event you don't sanitize `lineItemId`, and that gets passed in as `" 1; TRUNCATE TABLE ... ; --"`.

Comment: I was curious about your second suggestion about `lineItem`.

Comment: @vivek it's recommended to reduce the *live time* of a variable: the lines between declaration and the end of their scope. A variable that's visible may be accidentally misused. It may also be noise, distraction. You don't need this variable, it's not useful, so it has no reason to exist.

Comment: @janos Excellent explanation.